# unable to call onChange event on select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table structure like this below html code. Here i have a selectbox which is populated on page load from my database, i have given a inline function on the selectbox in order to call if user changes the selectbox value.. but its not calling the jquery function onChange of selectbox .. Please can you see why?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7TMrc/)

My jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
              $.fn.ActivityOptionChange = function(id) {  
                  alert("test"); 
            };
      ....
      ....
```

Html

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="table table-condensed TF" style="width: 100%;" id="table6">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="fltrow">
         <td><input id="flt0_table6" type="hidden" ct="0" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt1_table6" type="hidden" ct="1" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt2_table6" type="hidden" ct="2" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt3_table6" type="hidden" ct="3" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt4_table6" type="hidden" ct="4" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt5_table6" type="hidden" ct="5" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt6_table6" type="hidden" ct="6" class="flt"></td>
         <td><input id="flt7_table6" type="hidden" ct="7" class="flt"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="success">
         <td style="width: 15%;">S.no</td>
         <td style="width: 15%;">Activity Name</td>
         <td style="width: 5%;">Activity Option</td>
         <td style="width: 5%;">Time(HR:MIN)</td>
         <td style="width:10%;">cals</td>
         <td style="width: 5%;">distance</td>
         <td style="width: 5%;">Unit</td>
         <td style="width: 15%;">Submit</td>
      </tr>
      <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid44"></form>
      <tr id="formrowid44" class=" odd">
         <td style="width:5%;">1</td>
         <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize"><a href="localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/44/43">bicycling, BMX or mountain</a></td>
         <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">-</td>
         <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
            <div style="display:inline-flex;"><input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id44" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center;" value="00" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(44);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(44);" id="time-min-id44" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="00"></div>
         </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id44" value="8.5"><span id="cals-id44" class="cals">0.00</span></td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize"> <input name="distanceTxt" id="distance-Id44" type="text" style="width:50px;text-align:center;"> </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">

         </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">  <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(44);" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid45"></form>
      <tr id="formrowid45" class=" even">
         <td style="width:5%;">2</td>
         <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize"><a href="localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/45/43">bicycling/biking</a></td>
         <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
            <select name="activity_option_id" class="selectbox" onchange="$(this).ActivityOptionChange(45)" id="activity-opn-Id45">
               <option value="45_4.0">10 mph or less</option>
               <option value="47_6.0">10-11.9 mph, leisure, slow, light effort</option>
               <option value="46_8.0">general</option>
               <option value="48_16">greater then 20 mph, racing, not drafting</option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
            <div style="display:inline-flex;"><input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id45" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center;" value="00" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(45);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(45);" id="time-min-id45" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="00"></div>
         </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id45" value="4.0"><span id="cals-id45" class="cals">0.00</span></td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize"> <input name="distanceTxt" id="distance-Id45" type="text" style="width:50px;text-align:center;"> </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
            -
         </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">  <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(45);" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid49"></form>
      <tr id="formrowid49" class=" odd">
         <td style="width:5%;">3</td>
         <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize"><a href="localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/49/43">unicycling</a></td>
         <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">-</td>
         <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
            <div style="display:inline-flex;"><input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id49" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center;" value="00" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(49);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(49);" id="time-min-id49" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:25px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="00"></div>
         </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id49" value="5.0"><span id="cals-id49" class="cals">0.00</span></td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize"> <input name="distanceTxt" id="distance-Id49" type="text" style="width:50px;text-align:center;"> </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">

         </td>
         <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">  <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(49);" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `alert("test ` ... I wonder. You need it to be: `alert("test")`.

Comment: you have invalid html, forms dont belong between tr elements

Comment: @PatrickEvans How the form should be according to you then? http://jsfiddle.net/7TMrc/1/  in fiddle its working but i don know why in my localhost its not working

Comment: Your hidden inputs aren't terminated

Comment: In fact many of your inputs aren't terminated

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/7TMrc/2/
You have `<input ... >` when they need to be `<input ... />`

Comment: @Klors  the / close tag is there in my localhost html file but i don know why on page load the / is disappearing.. also my above code is running in FIrebox but in Chrome its not giving alert... any idea?

Comment: @Sundara The jsFiddle is running fine for me in Chrome. Is your code actually the same?

Comment: @Klors thanks for your time. Everything is okay, prev i was not able to run because i was having some syntax mistake in a library...  so that was affecting this function to run in my localhost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the jQuery .on('change') function:

```
$(document)ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '#activity_option_id', function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

Also see .[on() jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

EDIT: In response to your comment: If you have multiple select boxes that you need ID's for, you can implement a class based solution:

```
<select id="your_id_here1" class="formSelect" />
<select id="your_id_here2" class="formSelect" />

$(document)ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '.formSelect', function() {
        var elementID = this.id;
        alert(elementID);
    });
});
```

With this solution, any select box with a .formSelect class will have the change event bound to it and the ID of the particular input element changed will be displayed in the alert box.

Comment: i have to use inline function only because. i might have 100 forms with different id so in this case i don know the selectbox id then what to do ?

Comment: Please see the edit to my original answer to address that issue.